# Release resource on shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, locking, executorservice

I have a spring-boot app in which I use **ScheduledExecutorService** to create single threaded executor. In this single thread, I process database records. I acquire lock on many records to process them and want to release the lock as soon as JVM is shutdown. I have tried to register a JVM shutdown hook.

```
 // Create single threaded 
ScheduledExecutorService executor;= Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(dbRecordProcessor, 1000, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

// Registering shutdown hook
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                logger.info("Executing shutdown hook.....");
                executor.shutdown();
            }
        });

// 
DbRecordProcessor implements Runnable {
public void run() {
    try {
       // get all the records from DB by acquiring lock

    }catch(Exception e) {

    }finally {
     // Release the lock on record
     }
    // Acquire lock on records
    // loop on them
    // Process them
    // Release the lock after processing
  }
}
```

All I want is, When JVM shutdown hook is invoked, all the records on which lock was acquired must be released. I can not blindly say to "unlock" on all the records because some of the records might be locked by another instance SO I want to unlock only those records which are locked by this running instance. 
I wanted to know just by calling "executor.shutdown()", It would release the lock from all the records?  Please help me.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem or question?

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me what you are trying to achieve should be done with a transaction. Process data in batches of say 100 records not to make transaction too big, then when executor is shut down transaction will be rolled back and all the record level db locks will be released.

Answer (score 0):

`shutdown()` method will interrupt all idle worker and you can put cleanup code on interrupt  handle or in finally block.It is always advisable to do clean up .If you call `shutdownNow()` .It will interrupt all worker threads.